# QT/PySide processEvents call locks up

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Why would a call to processEvents block doing nothing for up to 9 seconds?

I have an application with a PySide-based QT interface, where the UI code sits as a decoupled layer over the lower level actual application logic.  When the user performs an action which executes lower level application logic that may run for a while, effectively what happens is:

1. Directly on the GUI thread a progress dialog is displayed.
2. Directly on the GUI thread, the lower level logic starts a worker thread.
3. Directly on the GUI thread, the lower level logic loops updating the progress dialog (indirectly/decoupled) and ticking the application event queue via QtGui.qApp.processEvents() (again indirectly/decoupled).
4. On the worker thread, QT functions are invoked (again indirectly/decoupled) in reaction to events, and these happen on the GUI thread via slots/signals, running when the GUI thread (as mentioned above) calls processEvents().
5. Directly on the GUI thread, before the loop exits, the last processEvents() call blocks for around 9 seconds.  This is after all the logic on the worker thread is over and done with, and there are no more functions waiting to run on it via signal/slot calls.  Nothing related to my application is happening in this call.  What is it doing there?  Why is it blocking?  I've tried passing in a max processing time of 300 ms and seeing if it exits, but this makes no difference.  The call locks up as long as it wants to.
6. The progress dialog closes and the user gets focus back.

This is all spread over a lot of files, implemented in a decoupled manner.  I'll try and provide snippets to give a picture of the flow.

The decoupled lower level logic worker loop:

```
    while not completed_event.wait(0.1) and not work_state.is_cancelled():
        work_completeness, work_description = work_state.get_completeness(), work_state.get_description()
        for client in self.clients:
            if work_completeness != last_completeness or work_description != last_description:
                client.event_prolonged_action_update(client is acting_client, work_description, step_count * work_completeness)
            # THE LAST CALL TO THE NEXT LINE LOCKS UP FOR NO REASON
            client.event_tick(client is acting_client)
        last_completeness, last_description = work_completeness, work_description
```

The PySide/QT layer client event_tick function:

```
def event_tick(self, active_client):
    # THIS IS WHERE THE LOCK UP HAPPENS
    QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
```

Signal/slot usage in the PySide/QT layer to get worker thread calls happening on the GUI thread:

```
def event_pre_line_change(self, active_client, line0, line_count):
    self.pre_line_change_signal.emit((line0, line_count))

def event_post_line_change(self, active_client, line0, line_count):
    self.post_line_change_signal.emit((line0, line_count))

def event_uncertain_reference_modification(self, active_client, data_type_from, data_type_to, address, length):
    self.uncertain_reference_modification_signal.emit((data_type_from, data_type_to, address, length))
```

The reason that I delegate the calls on the worker thread over to the GUI thread using signals/slots, is that this is what PySide/QT requires given they will update the UI.

Reproduction case if you want to dig deeper:

- Download and get [the code](https://github.com/rmtew/peasauce) running according to the GitHub project readme text.
- Download the [test file](https://mega.co.nz/#!gNUxWDzZ!DJ-owFOfmvx9Gr9Kqc9dXGJrUMQB3Pa3IeHsJtWEpyg) "NEURO" (<200KB in size) from mega (apologies, it was easiest site to upload to).
- Load NEURO in PeaSauce.
- Go to offset 0x1A19E (CTRL-G)
- Change the data type to code (Menu: Edit / Change address datatype / Code)
- Observe progress dialog come and go.
- Observe ~9 second lock up.